# Problema con reload de tabla en ajax

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

hago una tabla que consulta datos en una base de datos (la consulta se realiza en el body) sucede que en un momento dado para agregar datos hago uso de ajax pidiendo al final que me recargue la tabla para añadir el nuevo dato a la misma, lo he estado haciendo con otras tablas y no me dan ningun problema al realizar la recarga, pero cuando hago la recarga de esta la mayoria de los datos se pierde salvo por uno que esta definido por una variable.

este es el tbody donde hago las consultas

```
 <tbody>
            <?php
                $cont = 1;
               while($arreglo = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){
                       $longitud = strlen($arreglo["nom_tb"]);
                       $letra = substr($arreglo["nom_tb"],$longitud-2);
                       $nueva = "";
                       if($letra!="e"){
                            $nueva = $nueva.substr($arreglo["nom_tb"],0,$longitud-1);
                       }else{
                            $nueva = $nueva.substr($arreglo["nom_tb"],0,$longitud-2);
                       }
                   ?>
                   <tr>
                       <td><?php echo $arreglo["cod_bie"]; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $nueva; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $arreglo["nom_dep"]; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $arreglo["mod_bie"]; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $arreglo["mar_bie"]; ?></td>
                       <td><?php if($arreglo["est_bie"]=="F"){echo "Activo";}else{echo "Dañado";} ?></td>
                       <td>
                            <?php
                               $prestado = mysqli_query($conexion,"select * from prestamos where id_bie='".$arreglo["id_bie"]."'");
                                if($prestado->num_rows>0){
                                    echo "Sí";
                                }else{
                                    echo "No";
                                }
                            ?>
                       </td>
                       <td>M</td>
                       <td>E</td>
                   </tr>
                   <?php
                   $cont++;
               }
            ?>
        </tbody>
```

y esta la recarga

```
 $("#tabla").load(location.href+" #tabla");
```

lo demas no lo adjunto ya que como dije, al hacer la recarga en otras tablas no da ningun problema

EDIT:
El problema parece estar en que al recargar la tabla las variables definidas por un switch son ignoradas como esta:

```
switch($PC){
    case "categoria":
        $consul = "bienes.id_tb='$llave'";
    break;
    case "encargado":
        $consul = "bienes.ced_res='$llave'";
    break;
    case "modelo":
        $consul = "bienes.mod_bie='$llave'";
    break;
    case "marca":
        $consul = "bienes.mar_bie='$llave'";
    break;
    case "código":
        $consul = "bienes.cod_bie='$llave'";
    break;
    case "estado":
        if($llave=="Activo"){
            $llave = "F";
        }else{
            $llave = "D";
        }
        $consul = "bienes.est_bie='$llave'";
    break;
}
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion,"select * from bienes,tipo,departamentos where $consul and tipo.id_tb=bienes.id_tb and departamentos.id_dep=bienes.id_dep $con");
```

como podria hacer para que luego de la recarga la variable funcione?

Comment: Será que la consulta no devuelve esos campos supongo.  ¿ya has hecho un `print_r($arreglo);` dentro del while para ver lo que te devuelve?

Comment: tienes razon no devuelve los campos si devuelve algo el print_r pero muy pocas cosas en comparacion a la original, no entiendo porque

Comment: Si tu no lo entiendes que tienes acceso a ver lo que pone en **$consulta**, imagínate nosotros que tendriamos que adivinarlo todo, desde la consulta a tus tablas, je.

Comment: bueno encontre porque arroja menos habia otra variable consulta, pero al retirarla como la consulta original se define por un switch parece que al recargar la tabla no sabe cual usar